# POST variable not changing

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a form with some jQuery UI sortables that have `data-`attributes that get serialized into a hidden textbox, so when I send the form, my PHP script can look at the value of `$_POST["contents"]`(which is a string like this `1-2-2-1`) and pass it to my MySQL UPDATE query. The problem is, the reported value of the textbox before sending the form (from the javascript), is different than the one in `$_POST`.

**The form:**

```
<form method="post" action="?update">
    <input type="text" name="id" style="display:none" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="path" placeholder="Endereço Ex.: /pacotes/pureenergy" value="/some/path" /> <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Título da página" value="<?php echo $t;?>" /><br />
    <!-- Some stuff hidden for briefness -->
    <input type="text" id="ci" name="contents" style="display:none" value="1-2-2-1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Atualizar página" onclick="updateForm()">
</form>
```

**The Javascript:**

```
function updateForm() {
    var txt = $("#dropzone li:first-of-type").data("id");
    $("#dropzone li:not(:first-of-type)").each(function() {
        txt = txt+"-"+$(this).data("id");
    });
    $("#ci").text(txt);
    alert(txt);
}
```

**The PHP:**

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$p = $_POST["path"];
$t = $_POST["title"];
$c = $_POST["contents"];
mysql_query("UPDATE aruna.pages SET path='$p', title='$t', contents='$c' WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error());
```

The value reported by the javascript `alert()` is behaving as intended, but when I send the form, the value of the `$_POST["contents"]` is the same that was hardcoded in the HTML.

**EDIT:** PHP doesn't complain about `$_POST["contents"]` being unset, which it would if there was a typo.

Comment: What happens when you feed $("#ci").text to the alert?

Comment: It outputs the same as `alert(txt)`.

Comment: @ZZ-bb kaptainluffy fixed it, and no, because the form was only being sent after I confirmed the alert (which happens after the text is set). Turns out I was using the wrong jQ function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try .val() instead of .text()

Comment: It worked! Thanks man. What's the difference between `.val()` and `.text()`?

Comment: I actually don't know. I guess the .text() gets the .innerHTML property while .val() gets the value attribute. You can check it out on the jquery documentation itself

Comment: Oh, I've googled it now and got info out of jQ docs: `.text()` returns innertext (the text inside the element, excluding child tags. `.val()` is used to get/set the `value` attribute from any element that can have it.